# How to quit the and (or &) in the reference list?

Tags: bibliographies, apacite, spanish

Hello I am writting a thesis, so I want the style of elsevier's magazine, that is, without the **and** before the last author name:

> Donohue, K.A., Watts, D.R., Tracey, K.L., Greene, A.D., Kennelly, M., 2010. Mapping circulation
> in the Kuroshio Extension with an array of current and pressure recording inverted
> echo sounders. Journal of Atmospheric and Oceanic Technology 27, 507–527

No this:

> Donohue, K.A., Watts, D.R., Tracey, K.L., Greene, A.D., **and**  Kennelly, M., 2010. Mapping circulation
> in the Kuroshio Extension with an array of current and pressure recording inverted
> echo sounders. Journal of Atmospheric and Oceanic Technology 27, 507–527

I tried it with the next commands:

```
\BBAA
\BBAB
```

But they quit  both in the text and the reference list; I need only in the list.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,openany]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[left=2.3cm,right=2.3cm,top=2.1cm,bottom=2.3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb} % Paquetes matemáticos
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Codificación .tex
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Codificación .pdf
\usepackage{graphicx} % Para insertar imágenes
\usepackage{lipsum} % Para texto falso
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[toc,nonumberlist]{glossaries} % toc para agregarlo al índice general.
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{nomencl} % Paquete para nomenclatura
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage{suffix}
\usepackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{glossaries}{Deprecated command}% Removes warning starting with "Deprecated command"

\begin{document}
\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{}
%/// renewcommand
 \renewcommand{\BOthers}[1]{et al.\hbox{}}  % Esto es para cambiar el "y" por et al. en las citas en el texto.

Se  ha documentado   que en la mayoría de la zonas de subducción, donde ocurren los eventos sísmicos más fuertes(\cite{kato2012propagation}) ....

% Referencias
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{\centering \Large REFERENCIAS}
\bibliography{bibliografia.bib}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{REFERENCIAS}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An up-front comment, prompted by your observation that you "want the [bibliography] style of Elsevier [journals]": To truly replicate the Elsevier bibliographic formatting style, you shouldn't use the `apacite` bibliography style and `apacite` citation management package. Instead, you should (a) use the `elsarticle-harv` bibliography style and (b) employ the `natbib` package with the option `authoryear`.

Let's assume, though, that you in fact do want to employ the `apacite` bibliography style and that you still wish to eliminate the `&` (or `and` or `y`) conjunction before the final author in the list of authors or editors. Two additional comments come to mind:

1. You should *under absolutely no circumstance* load *both* the `apacite` and `natbib` packages. If you wish to use `natbib`-type citation commands -- such as `\citep` and `\citet` -- while employing the `apacite` package and eponymous bibliography style, you should run `\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}` along with `\bibliographystyle{apacite}`. (Of course, if you do *not* need the `natbib`-type citation commands, you shouldn't employ the `natbibapa` option.)
2. Since you load the `babel` package with the `spanish` language option, you need to run

   ```
   \AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\BBAA}{\unskip}}
   ```

   instead of either `\renewcommand{\BBAA}{\unskip}` or `\renewcommand{\BBAA}{}` in order to get the desired suppression of the conjunction particle in the formatted bibliographic entries.

---

First, the citation call-outs produced by `\citet` and `\citep` for the test document shown below:

[image]

Second, the formatted bibliographic entry:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,openany,spanish]{book}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{bibliografia.bib}
@misc{kato2012propagation,
  author = "A. Kato and B. Lato and C. Mato", 
  title  = "Propagation", 
  year   = 2012,
}
\end{filecontents}

% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\BBAA}{\unskip}}

\begin{document}
\citet{kato2012propagation}, \citep{kato2012propagation}.
\bibliography{bibliografia}
\end{document}
```

Comment: OMG !!! It worked, thank you so much.